# Windows 10: Cannot connect to HTTPS web sites using Internet Explorer

Tags: networking, windows-10, https, internet-explorer-11

After a clean install of Windows 10 Pro on a new machine, I cannot access HTTPS web sites using Internet Explorer 11.

- Both Chrome and Edge work fine!
- HTTP web sites in Internet Explorer work fine!
- There was an anti virus installed (Avast), which I removed while troubleshooting.
- The computer is connected to a wired network that is set as a "private network" and Windows Firewall is disabled for both "private profile" and "domain profile".
- There is no proxy on the network, but I've also disabled all proxy auto detection and manual proxy settings in the Settings up.
- Some other software that needs to access the network, such as Onedrive and the Dropbox installer, also fail to connect - I can only assume they try to access HTTPS using the same method that IE uses (but not other browsers).
- I've enabled all SSL versions in Internet Explorer's advanced internet options (even though SSL 2 and 3 are disabled by default).

I'm currently at a lost as to what to do next.

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Chrome and Edge both use the same certificate store as IE11.  Which means this isn't a certificate store problem.  Which means you should reset IE11, see if that helps, I assume IE11 at some point did actually work.

Comment: @Ramhound: IE11 never worked on this installation, to the best of my knowledge - this is a clean install. I never tried to use iexplore before the dropbox installer started crapping.

Comment: Try my suggestion.

Comment: Try installing and uninstalling avast.

Comment: Is the system time correct?

Comment: @Ramhound: tried it, not working.

Comment: @davidbaumann - currently avast is not installed.

Comment: @Burgi - yes, the system time is correct.

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: @DavidPostill: "This page can't be displayed" . See this for how it looks (except the address): http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Yo7PWQrs11E/Usy2eHpAnKI/AAAAAAAADUo/dnCIv8EzkW4/s1600/pagecannotbedisplayed.png

Comment: Maybe you're missing some key cipher suite. Perhaps someone can look at the output of `Get-TlsCipherSuite` in your PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have solved itself, after I enabled "Insider Preview" fast track, installed all updates, let the computer sleep on it for a night, installed more updates that were available in the morning, and restarted a couple of times.

Now it works fine. Boggles the mind. I'm glad my main system is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset Internet Explorer to get original settings.
Tools\Internet Options\Advanced\Reset (delete personal data)

Comment: That's what @Ramhoubd suggested. No worky.